# Integral of the inverse of a "simple" sum

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

$$\Large \int_{0}^{\infty} \left (\frac{1}{ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k} \right)~ dx$$

It seems like this converges to $\approx \frac{1}{2}$ but when I try to calculate this I get really stuck, and for no reason!

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \frac{1}{1-x} $$

And so the integral becomes:

$$\large \int_{0}^{\infty} (1-x)~ dx = \text{Does not converge}$$

Even if I use the "regular" geometric progression sum $$ \frac{ 1 \cdot (x^n - 1)}{x-1} $$

Where $n \to \infty$ (number of "elements" in the progression) it seems to actually converge to $0$.

Why these $2$ tries failed? I don't get it... what is the correct way to find the value?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson As we have the upper bound of the summation tends to infinity it looks like a triangle, are you sure it diverges? (thus it is $\frac{1}{2}$)

Comment: @AaronHendrickson that is not correct. As written this definitely converges to $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: It depends on how you interpret $\,1/(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k)\,$ for $\,x\ge 1.\,$
As written the summation does **not** converge and is not defined which implies
that its reciprocal is also not defined. You can't integrate an undefined function.

Comment: The problem is that your evaluation of the summation in that way is only valid in a given domain, which your integral goes outside of

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to break it up into two cases: for $x \in (0,1)$, and $x \in (1,\infty)$. Then you have that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n} \, dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n} \, dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n} \, dx$$

For the first one, we can use your approach to get that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n} dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1/(1-x)} dx = \int_0^1 (1-x) dx = x - \frac{x^2}{2} \bigg|_{x=0}^1 = \frac 1 2$$

This holds because (whenever $|x|<1$: note that it doesn't hold if $|x| \ge 1$!), then

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

If $x > 1$, however, then $\sum_{n=0}^N x^n \to \infty \implies 1 / \sum_{n=0}^N x^n \to 0$, and so

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^Nx^n} \, dx \stackrel{N \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$

though I think being able to do this limiting process requires additional justification (e.g. dominated convergence, perhaps?). But either way with that in mind, then we should be able to see that (if just intuitively), that the second integral should be $0$, and, overall, you get

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n} \, dx = \frac 1 2$$

Answer (score 5):

This is not exactly the most sensible approach to the problem but it does offer another way to get the solution and I'm a sucker for special functions. We have
$$
I=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-x}{1-x^n}\,\mathrm dx+\int_1^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-x}{1-x^n}\,\mathrm dx.
$$
For $n\geq 0$ the integrand of the first integral is nonnegative and bounded above by one, which is integrable on $[0,1]$. Likewise, for $n\geq2$ the integrand of the second integral is nonnegative and bounded above by $(1+x+x^2)^{-1}$ which again is integrable on $[1,\infty)$; hence, by argument of dominated convergence
$$
I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{1-x}{1-x^n}\,\mathrm dx+\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^\infty\frac{1-x}{1-x^n}\,\mathrm dx.
$$
Substituting $t=x^n$ and $t=x^{-n}$ into the first and second integral, respectively, we have from the [integral representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.16.07.0001.01) of the harmonic numbers:
$$
I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(H_{-1/n}-H_{1/n-1}+H_{2/n-1}-H_{-2/n}\right),
$$
which upon application of the [functional identities](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.16.17.0006.01) and [recurrence identities](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.16.17.0003.01) for $H_z$ simplifies to
$$
I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{n}(\cot(\pi/n)-\cot(2\pi/n))=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The limit of the partial sums evaluates to different things depending on where in the domain of integration we are

$$\int_0^1 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-x}{1-x^n}\:dx + \int_1^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-x}{1-x^n}\:dx = \int_0^1 1-x\:dx + \int_1^\infty 0\:dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Why can you change the domain of integration as such?

Comment: @user12686317 I have not changed anything, this is simply the definition of integration. You integrate on subsets and add all of the pieces up.

Comment: But why one limit is $1-x$ but the second is $0$ ?

Comment: Also, why did my first attempt fail?

Comment: @user12686317 why do you think the limits evaluate differently depending on what $x$ is? Where is the $n$ we are taking a limit of? The answer to these questions will tell you why your attempted failed.

Comment: My incorrect conclusion led me to further investigation. For what its worth, both integrals can be evaluated in terms of Digamma and harmonic numbers (which are really one in the same). The first integral on $[0,1]$ evaluates to $\frac{\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n}$ which yields a limit of $1/2$. For the second integral we have $\frac{H_{-\frac{1}{n}}-H_{-\frac{2}{n}}}{n}$ which also gives the correct limit of zero.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson that is an impressive amount of effort! However, I want to warn you that going along that path in the future may give you a wrong answer. In your method you solved the integral then took the limit, but in general we have to be careful that swapping the limit and the integral is justified. It is always easier to take limits then integrate when we can, and thankfully this problem (unusually) provides the limit inside of the integral.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I was just about to add that! Haha. Yes, you still have to justify the interchange of limits using dominated convergence or some variant thereof.